# Error setting the CPU scaling governor through app

Tags: android, root

I'm creating a simple Android app that should set the CPU Scaling Governor.

To achieve this I made this function:

```
public static void setCurrentGovernor(String governor){
    Process process;
    try{
        String cpufreq_path= "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq";
        String cmd = "echo `"+governor+"` > "+cpufreq_path+"/scaling_governor ";
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su","-c",cmd});
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problem is that this function won't work, plus superuser always prompts me for permissions, is there a way to give it root permission only at first app boot?

This function is called inside an onitemselectedlistener of a spinner, right after this function there's another one which fetches data from cpufreq files to update the view, but if i do `cat scaling_governor` i get the old governor, so it is not a faulty update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This more solid code solved my problem: 
[Link](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.it/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html)